# Where is the point at which adding additional cores or CPUs doesn’t improve the performance at all?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multicore

> *Adding a second core or CPU might increase the performance of your parallel program, but it is unlikely to double it. Likewise, a
>   four-core machine is not going to execute your parallel program four
>   times as quickly— in part because of the overhead and coordination
>   described in the previous sections. However, the design of the
>   computer hardware also limits its ability to scale. You can expect a
>   significant improvement in performance, but it won’t be 100 percent
>   per additional core, and there will almost certainly be a point at
>   which adding additional cores or CPUs doesn’t improve the performance
>   at all.

*

I read the paragraph above from a book. But I don't get the last sentence.
So, Where is the point at which adding additional cores or CPUs doesn’t improve the performance at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a serial program and a parallel version of the same program then the parallel program has to do some operations that the serial program does not, specifically operations concerned with coordinating the operations of the multiple processors.  These contribute to what is often called 'parallel overhead' -- additional work that a parallel program has to do.  This is one of the factors that makes it difficult to get 2x speed-up on 2 processors, 4x on 4 or 32000x on 32000 processors.

If you examine the code of a parallel program you will often find segments which are serial, that is which only use one processor while the others are idle.  There are some (fragments of) algorithms which are not parallelisable, and there are some operations which are often not parallelised but which could be: I/O operations for instance, to parallelise these you need some sort of parallel I/O system.  This 'serial fraction' provides an irreducible minimum time for your computation.  [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) explains this, and that article provides a useful starting point for your further reading.

Even when you do have a program which is well parallelised the scaling (ie the way speed-up changes as the number of processors increases) does not equal 1.  For most parallel programs the size of the parallel overhead (or the amount of processor time which is devoted to operations which are only necessary for parallel computing) increases as some function of the number of processors.  This often means that adding processors adds parallel overhead and at some point in the scaling of your program and jobs the increase in overhead cancels out (or even reverses) the increase in processor power.  The article on Amdahl's Law also covers Gustafson's Law which is relevant here.

I've phrased this all in very general terms, no consideration of current processor and computer architectures; what I am describing are features of parallel computation (as currently understood) not of any particular program or computer.

I flat out disagree with @Daniel Pittman's assertion that these issues are of only theoretical concern.  Some of us are working very hard to make our programs scale to very large numbers of processors (1000s).  And almost all desktop and office development these days, and most mobile development too, targets multi-processor systems and using all those cores is a major concern.

Finally, to answer your question, at what point does adding processors no longer increase execution speed, now that is an architecture- and program-dependent question.  Happily, it is one that is amenable to empirical investigation.  Figuring out the scalability of parallel programs, and identifying ways of improving it, are a growing niche within the software engineering 'profession'.

Answer (score 2):

@High Performance Mark is right. This happens when you are trying to solve a fixed size problem in the fastest possible way, so that Amdahl' law applies. It does not (usually) happen when you are trying to solve in a fixed time a problem. In the former case, you are willing to use the same amount of time to solve a problem

- whose size is bigger;
- whose size is exactly the same as before, but with a greeter accuracy.

In this situation, Gustafson's law applies.

So, let's go back to fixed size problems.
In the speedup formula you can distinguish these components:

- Inherently sequential computations:  σ(n)
- Potentially parallel computations: ϕ(n)
- Overhead (Communication operations etc):  κ(n,p)

and the speedup for *p* processors for a problem size *n* is

[image]

Adding processors reduces the computation time but increases the communication time (for message-passing algorithms; it increases the synchronization overhead etcfor shared-memory algorithm); if we continue adding more processors, at some point the communication time increase will be larger than the corresponding computation time decrease.

When this happens, the parallel execution time begins to increase.
Speedup is inversely proportional to execution time, so that its curve begins to decline.
For any fixed problem size, there is an optimum number of processors that minimizes the overall parallel execution time.

Here is how you can compute exactly (analytical solution in closed form) the point at which you get no benefit by adding additional processors (or cores if you prefer). 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, of course, "it depends", but in the current world of shared memory multi-processors the short version is "when traffic coordinating shared memory or other resources consumes all available bus bandwidth and/or CPU time".

That is a very theoretical problem, though.  Almost nothing scales well enough to keep taking advantage of more cores at small numbers.  Few applications benefit from 4, less from 8, and almost none from 64 cores today - well below any theoretical limitations on performance.

Comment: I agree on the memory bandwidth limitation which is a serious problem when targetting shared-memory multi-processor architectures. However, I strongly disagree with your assertion that these problems are only theoretical. Much of the effort put in high performance computing aims to leverage those limitations and often succeed in pushing the scalability limit beyond a few hundreds/thousands cores.

Comment: -1 "That is a very theoretical problem, though. Almost nothing scales well enough to keep taking advantage of more cores at small numbers. Few applications benefit from 4, less from 8, and almost none from 64 cores today - well below any theoretical limitations on performance". This is just nonsense. Two of my eight Xeon cores can max out the entire system's main memory bandwidth. Applications that thrash are not expected to scale in theory and don't scale in practice. That is not "a very theoretical problem", it dictates how I write my applications.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking x86 that architecture is more or less at its limits. @ 3 GHz electricity travels 10 cm (actually somewhat less) per Hz, the die is about 1 cm square, components have to be able to switch states in that single Hz (1/3000000000 of a second). The current manufacturing process (22nm) gives interconnections that are 88 (silicon) atoms wide (I may have misunderstood this). With this in mind you realize that there isn't that much more that can be done with physics here (how narrow can an interconnection be? 10 atoms? 20?). At the other end the manufacturer, to be able to market a device as "higher performing" than its predecessor, adds a core which theoretically doubles the processing power.

"Theoretically" is not actually completely true. Some specially written applications will subdivide a large problem into parts that are small enough to be contained inside a single core and its exclusive caches (L1 & L2). A part is given to the core and it processes for a significant amount of time without accessing the L3 cache or RAM (which it shares with other cores and therefore will be where collisions/bottlenecks will occur). Upon completion it writes its results to RAM and receives a new part of the problem to work on.

If a core spends 99% of its time doing internal processing and 1% reading from and writing to shared memory (L3 cache and RAM) you could have an additional 99 cores doing the same thing because, in the end, the limiting factor will be the number of accesses the shared memory is capable of. Given my example of 99:1 such an application could make efficient use of 100 cores.

With more common programs - office, ie, etc - the extra processing power available will hardly be noticed. Some parts of the programs may have smaller parts written to take advantage of multiple cores and if you know which ones you may notice that those parts of the programs are much faster.

The 3 GHz was used as an example because it works well with the speed of light which is 300000000 meters/sec. I read recently that AMD's latest architecture was able to execute at 5 GHz but this was with special coolers and, even then, it was slower (processed less) than an intel i7 running at a significantly slower frequency.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on your program architecture/design. Adding cores improves parallel processing. If your program is not doing anything in parallel but only sequentially, adding cores would not improve its performance at all. It might improve other things though like framework internal processing (if you're using a framework).

So the more parallel processing is allowed in your program the better it scales with more cores. But if your program has limits on parallel processing (by design or nature of data) it will not scale indefinitely. It takes a lot of effort to make program run on hundreds of cores mainly because of growing overhead, resource locking and required data coordination. The most powerful supercomputers are indeed massively multi-core but writing programs that can utilize them is a significant effort and they can only show their power in an inherently parallel tasks.